# Python requests resolve eBay.de HCaptcha with 2Captcha

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

i hope someone can help me solve with python requests/mechanicalsoup and the 2captcha API eBay.de HCaptcha.
The documentation:
https://2captcha.com/de/p/hcaptcha

The problem isn't with 2captcha its a problem from eBay. if i post the request i get this error: "b'CSRF_VALIDATION_ERR'"

The API Key is working, if you want to try it.

My Code:

```
from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha
import mechanicalsoup
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))))

user_agents = [
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36",
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0"]
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.set_user_agent(user_agents[0])

url = 'https://www.ebay.de/bin/purchaseHistory?item=233592905862&rt=nc&_trksid=p2047675.l2564'
res = browser.open(url)
form = res.soup.find('form', {'id': 'captcha_form'})

srt = form.find('input', {'name': 'srt'})['value']
ru = form.find('input', {'name': 'ru'})['value']
cptap = form.find('input', {'name': 'cptap'})['value']
appName = form.find('input', {'name': 'appName'})['value']
cptrdbpid = form.find('input', {'name': 'cptrdbpid'})['value']
iia = form.find('input', {'name': 'iia'})['value']
iiz = form.find('input', {'name': 'iiz'})['value']
iim = form.find('input', {'name': 'iim'})['value']

# browser.launch_browser()

api_key = os.getenv('APIKEY_2CAPTCHA', 'ad0d381411ecaf40977c8a18f719321e')
solver = TwoCaptcha(api_key)
try:
result = solver.hcaptcha(
sitekey=cptrdbpid,
url=url,
)

except Exception as e:
print('Not solved')

else:
print('solved: ' + str(result))

payload = {"srt": srt,
"ru": ru,
"cptap": cptap,
"appName": appName,
"cptrdbpid": cptrdbpid,
"iia": iia,
"iiz": iiz,
"iim": iim,
"g-recaptcha-response": result['code'],
"h-captcha-response": result['code'],
"captchaTokenInput": "%7B%22guid%22%3A%" + cptrdbpid + '22%22%2C%22provider%22%3A%22hcaptcha%22%2C%22appName%22%3A%22orch%22%2C%22token%22%3A%22' +
result['code'] + "%22%7D"
}

headers = {
"accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
"accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"accept-language": "de-DE,de;q=0.9",
"cache-control": "max-age=0",
"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"origin": "https://www.ebay.de",
"referer": browser.url,
"sec-ch-ua": '"Google Chrome";v="95", "Chromium";v="95", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
"sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
"sec-ch-ua-platform": "Windows",
"sec-fetch-dest": "document",
"sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
"sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
"sec-fetch-user": "?1",
"upgrade-insecure-requests": "1"}
res = browser.post('https://www.ebay.de/splashui/captcha_submit', json=payload, allow_redirects=True, timeout=15, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, you can try to go through it with your hands through the browser and get this error.
I get this error when:

1. Session expired
2. Incorrect data
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qj4B.png)

In your case, you need to pass cookies and the correct captcha Token Input

Use correct guid
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsK9B.png)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i just checked it. There are some more requests needed to get the guid. i will try it tomorrow. Did you completly figured it out?